# Eclipse Msys64 - Weird gcc compiler output? *** Updated *** Eclipse wraps debug args with '

Tags: gcc, output, msys2

Anyhow, when I compile and run the code it runs differently under debug and run (neither work). When I debug the code and step through I get completely weird results which correspond to the behavior. See the screenshot below.

[Weird result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXuZP.png)

**** New information.

As Konstantin pointed out, there is a ' in my input line. I also noticed it a few minutes ago. My vision is not that good.

However, there is no ' in the command line I give the program.

It is

-iC:\Users\Brian\Documents\icezum -y

pasted directly from the debug configuration of Eclipse and later in the program I have another string with a ' prepended to it. The Eclipse run configuration is the same.

*** More information: it seems that Eclipse or msys2 has decided to pass 
'C:\Users\Brian\Documents\icezum' to my program instead of 
C:\Users\Brian\Documents\icezum

*** Updated: Eclipse Neon when debugging msys2 wraps all command line arguments with a single quote ('). It does not seem to do so for run arguments.

When I filter out the ' s I get the same result while debugging as while running.

I coded my way around the ['] problem but it is nasty.

Thanks again

Comment: Your line "'-iicezum'" first character is '\''

Please note quotes.

Line (without quotes): '-iicezum'

Character (without quotes): \'

Comment: Konstantin Thank you for that. My vision isn't what it used to be and I just noticed it. Here is the problem however: my run configuration is this (copied directly from Eclipse)  -iC:\Users\Brian\Documents\icezum -y so there is no ['] when I start the program. Not only that but when I patch around this, later on in the program another string get a ['] prepended to it.

Comment: Relevant bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494246

Comment: It sounds like there is a bug in your program and also a bug in Eclipse.  Could you try to separate the two issues and ask them as two separate questions, with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for each?  I'd like to help you debug the actual problem in your program, but without an MCVE there is not much I can do.

Comment: David   FRob nailed it: Eclipse Neon (which I am using) has a bug which wraps debug command line arguments (but not run command line arguments) with a quote so -itest in Eclipse becomes '-itest' in the program. One it became obvious I just stripped out all the ' from the command line argument and carried on.  The other bug was because in msys2/Mingw it would not read a text file unless I opened the file with the 'b' flag (i.e. "rb+") even though it was a text file with no control characters and Cygwin was happy with it. So, that was easy enough to correct as well.